# Child object not following parent

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, parent

I created an 'Enemy' object (Rigid Body) which has a 'Weapon' object (Rigid Body as well) as a child and the 'Weapon' object in turn has a child called 'Muzzle' (No collision, an Empty object). The 'Weapon' object rotates with its parent in a normal fashion, but the 'Muzzle' goes on a rather weird trajectory when the 'Enemy' rotates (like a very narrow ellipse, might as well not be an ellipse at all but some other random curve). Any ideas how to solve this? P.S. Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: You should probably post some screenshots of your scene, objects, logic, constraints, physics options, and other relevant data. Possibly also a as **simplified as possible** [file reproducing the problem](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make "Muzzle" and "Weapon" one object,with **Ctrl J**, and set "Enemy" as its parent.

Comment: I actually deleted the 'Muzzle' and wrote a script for the 'Weapon' to add a bullet at a certain offset from its own position. Thank you!